# Eclipse scolling very slow on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Tags: eclipse, osx-mountain-lion

I have Eclipse (Kepler) on Mac osx 10.8.5, everything works out pretty good, except that the scrolling is lagging like crazy... I have followed some suggestions to update java to java 7, and i see that eclipse is using 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjava.dylib

I also increased eclipse jvm to use bigger memory size. Here's my eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1028m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1028m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

So I'm not sure what else I need to do to fix this. Anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: If anyone is intersested, there seems to be a [bounty of $500](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366471) for anyone who fixes this! See comment 153 in [this thread](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366471).

Answer (score 5):

Have the same issue with MBP Retina and OSX 10.9 with JRE 1.6. I think that it is related to not optimized drawing of content in editor's window. If you f.e. shrink eclipse's window it will operate faster. In full screen mode it took up to 80% of one processor's core.
BTW there is already a bug report for that issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366471